# What will be the image of an annulus under $f(z)=\log z$?

Tags: complex-analysis

We are in complex plane and $\log z$ is the principal $\log$. The set $A= \left\{ z \in \mathbb {C} : e^{-\frac\pi 4} < |z| < e^{\frac\pi 4}, \Re z <0 \right\}$ is our annulus. How do I sketch the image of $A$ under $f(z)$?

Comment: Is there any $i$ to the exponents $e^{-\pi/4}$ ?

Comment: @mathvision note that is the absolute value of z

Comment: What is "the principal log" in your terminology? In my terminology the principal branch of the logarithm is defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]$, hence it's not defined on all of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points in $A$ can be written as $re^{i\theta}$ for $e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}<r<e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}$ and $\pi<\theta<2\pi$.
$$\ln(re^{i\theta})=\ln(r)+i\theta$$

Let's define $x=\ln(r)$. The domain $e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}<r<e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}$ is equivalent to the domain $-\frac{\pi}{4}<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$

Renaming $y=\theta$, you get the rectangle defined by $x+iy$ for $-\frac{\pi}{4}<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\pi<y<2\pi$